# Regarding Scissor test in fragment operations

Tags: opengl, graphics

Why glScissor is a part of fragment operations, what it is not part of clipping operations as it is more likely to be clipping?

Comment: It is not a clipping (at least not of geometry).It just restricts the area of fragment shader output.For the geometry clipping glViewport is used.glScissor does pixel "clipping in screenspace

Comment: @MichaelIV  then what is the advantage of clipping in screenspace? I mean why specifically clipping in screenspace is needed if we have clipping in assembly stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary advantage is that unlike primitive clipping, the scissor box affects operations like `glClear (...)`. Many people expect that calling `glViewport (...)` with some rectangle will define the region of the screen that is cleared during buffer clears, only to be surprised later on :) The scissor box is what you use to restrict ***any*** raster operation to a certain region of the screen, not just projected geometry (e.g. viewport mapping).

It is definitely not clipping in the traditional sense. It is more akin to the boolean tests for stencil/depth than clipping, which (may) modify geometry during primitive assembly. No polygons are going to be modified when you use a scissor box and scissor tests, instead rasterization will be skipped for any portion of a primitive that lies outside of the test rectangle. Clipping, on the other hand, may terminate entire primitives long before they reach rasterization.

Comment: Could you please explain: "Many people expect that calling glViewport (...) with some rectangle will define the region of the screen that is cleared during buffer clears, only to be surprised later on :) "

Comment: @debonair: At least once every few months on Stack Overflow, someone asks a question to the effect: "Why does not setting `glViewport (...)` affect which part of the screen `glClear (...)` works on?" The viewport affects where projected images map onto the window, but does not define the actual boundaries for raster operations.